# Quelle serait une façon plus correcte de dire « Je regarderai la télévision à la prochaine pluie »?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Comment mieux exprimer l’idée en question de sorte qu’elle réponde au bon usage. Disons que le tour « à la... » me laisse hésitant sur le plan syntaxique, peut-être devrais-je préférer l’usage d’une locution prépositive comme « lors de », mais j’ai l’impression que cela ne fait qu’alourdir inutilement la phrase...

Merci!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quelques suggestions:

> Je regarderai la télévision la prochaine fois qu'il pleuvra/va pleuvoir.

> Je regarderai la télévision quand il repleuvra/va repleuvoir.

> Quand il pleuvra de nouveau, je regarderai la télévision.